# file pulled from s3 using .ebextensions config cannot be accessed from webapp

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to pull a privatekey from S3 into my elastic beanstalk app without adding it as an environment variable (heard that was not safe). I can pull this file from S3 onto my instance just fine (verified by SSH-ing into the instance and inspecting the file). However, I cannot access this file from my app. I am running a Flask python app. When trying to access the file from my python app I get a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/server.key'` error.

(1) Is this how very sensitive secrets should be handled?
(2) Any idea why I can inspect the file when I SSH in, but not from my app?

I have a `.ebextensions/privatekey.config` like so:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-111111111111"]
          roleName: 
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting": 
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
files:
  # Private key
  /etc/server.key:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-111111111111/mycoolapp/server.key
```

And I am just trying a simple:

```
with open("/etc/server.key") as file:  
    data = file.read()
```

in python.

Comment: is your app pointing to the server or to your local host?

Comment: @aws_apprentice I might not be understanding your question correctly, but its running on aws. I am not running this off of my local machine.